# Magento 'Base table or view not found' System Downgrade

Tags: php, mysql, magento, mage

im trying to update my Magento from 1.1.8 to 3.x... and it's a nightmare!

My database is backed up, ive tried removing 'catalog_setup' from the core_resource table, it stops this error but brings up another error about duplicate entrys @ row 1. I was going to install v1.7 and just try pull all the catalog_ tables over but is this going to fail most likely?

I did an upgrade to version 2.x last night but then it didn't work and since trying to rever back I just get this error:

```
 PDOException Object
(
[message:protected] => SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'website_magento.catalog_product' doesn't exist
[string:private] => 
[code:protected] => 42S02
[file:protected] => /home/website/domains/[website]/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
[line:protected] => 187
[trace:private] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home/website/domains/[website]/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
                [line] => 187
                [function] => query
                [class] => PDO
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal
WHERE (entity_id in (
    SELECT entity_id FROM catalog_product WHERE type_id = 'downloadable'
)) and attribute_id = 64
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home/website/domains/[website]/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
                [line] => 249
                [function] => raw_query
                [class] => Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal
WHERE (entity_id in (
    SELECT entity_id FROM catalog_product WHERE type_id = 'downloadable'
)) and attribute_id = 64
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home/website/domains/[website]/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                [line] => 493
                [function] => multi_query
                [class] => Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal
WHERE (entity_id in (
    SELECT entity_id FROM catalog_product WHERE type_id = 'downloadable'
)) and attribute_id = 64

                    )

            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home/website/domains/[website]/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/sql/downloadable_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php
                [line] => 52
                [function] => run
                [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal
WHERE (entity_id in (
    SELECT entity_id FROM catalog_product WHERE type_id = 'downloadable'
)) and attribute_id = 64

                    )

            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home/website/domains/[website]/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                [line] => 268
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => /home/website/domains/[website]/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/sql/downloadable_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php
                    )

                [function] => include
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home/website/domains/[website]/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                [line] => 178
                [function] => _modifyResourceDb
                [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => upgrade
                        [1] => 0.1.0
                        [2] => 0.1.14
                    )

            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home/website/domains/[website]/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                [line] => 145
                [function] => _upgradeResourceDb
                [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 0.1.0
                        [1] => 0.1.14
                    )

            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home/website/domains/[website]/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                [line] => 120
                [function] => applyUpdates
                [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home/website/domains/[website]/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php
                [line] => 215
                [function] => applyAllUpdates
                [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                [type] => ::
                [args] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home/website/domains/[website]/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php
                [line] => 243
                [function] => init
                [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Config
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

            )

        [10] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home/website/domains/[website]/public_html/app/Mage.php
                [line] => 424
                [function] => init
                [class] => Mage_Core_Model_App
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                        [1] => store
                        [2] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

            )

        [11] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home/website/domains/[website]/public_html/app/Mage.php
                [line] => 443
                [function] => app
                [class] => Mage
                [type] => ::
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                        [1] => store
                        [2] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

            )

        [12] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home/website/domains/[website]/public_html/index.php
                [line] => 46
                [function] => run
                [class] => Mage
                [type] => ::
                [args] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

    )

[errorInfo] => Array
    (
        [0] => 42S02
        [1] => 1146
        [2] => Table 'website_magento.catalog_product' doesn't exist
    )

  )

  Error in file: "/home/website/domains/[website]/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/sql/downloadable_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php" - SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'website_magento.catalog_product' doesn't exist

  #0 /home/website/domains/[website]/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(286): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
  #1 /home/website/domains/[website]/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(178): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '0.1.0', '0.1.14')
  #2 /home/website/domains/[website]/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(145): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('0.1.0', '0.1.14')
  #3 /home/website/domains/[website]/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(120): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
  #4 /home/website/domains/[website]/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(215): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
  #5 /home/website/domains/[website]/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(243): Mage_Core_Model_Config->init(Array)
  #6 /home/website/domains/[website]/public_html/app/Mage.php(424): Mage_Core_Model_App->init('', 'store', Array)
  #7 /home/website/domains/[website]/public_html/app/Mage.php(443): Mage::app('', 'store', Array)
  #8 /home/website/domains/[website]/public_html/index.php(46): Mage::run()
  #9 {main}
```

Comment: could you please add more detail about what is the error that you have faced & in which stage ?

Comment: Hello man from the future. I wish I have magento 3 source code.